# Is there a way to manually retry a step in Argo DAG workflow?

Tags: argo-workflows

Argo UI shows a "Retry" button for DAG workflows but if a step fails and I use it to retry it always fails to retry. Is manual retry even supported in Argo?

Comment: I believe there's a way to retry an entire workflow, but not an individual step. When you say "it always fails to retry," do you mean the retry isn't triggered, or that the workflow consistently fails during retried runs?

Comment: From my experimentation, if you retry a workflow all failed steps will retry, but it seems like there is a bug when using the CLI to select specific failed tasks: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/11279

They've labeled it a P3 so maybe someone will pick it up.